# Given Polar Coordinates - Find the rectangular coordinates of a centroid.

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, centroid

I'm having trouble with this question on my Calculus III homework. I'm not really sure how to go about this one honestly.

> A lamina is bounded by the curve $r = 2\cos(3θ)\space$ when $-π/6 <= θ <= π/6$. Assuming a constant density, $ρ =  k$, give the rectangular coordinates of the centroid.

For clarity of the question, and clarity of what type of answer I am looking for:

> My professor taught me the following: $$M_x = \iint y\rho(x,y)dA$$ $$M_y = \iint x\rho(x,y)dA$$ $$m = \iint \rho(x,y)dA$$ The answer I need is, $$(\bar x, \bar y) = \left(\frac{M_y}{m},\frac{M_x}{m}\right)$$ In addition, I was taught that $$ x = r\cos(\theta) $$ $$ y = r\sin(\theta) $$ when converting between polar and rectangular coordinates.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to find centre of mass, right ?

Comment: Yes. @A---B that is correct.

Comment: The solution that you accepted below is incorrect. Please see my answer below that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first calculate the total mass of the centroid.  The total mass $M$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
M&=\int_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/6} \int_0^{2\cos(3\theta)}\rho \,r\,dr\,d\theta\\\\
&=4\rho\int_0^{\pi/6}\cos^2(3\theta)\,d\theta\\\\
&=\frac\pi3\rho
\end{align}$$

Because of the symmetry of the centroid, we expect the center of mass to lie on the $x$-axis.   In fact, the center of mass, $\vec r_{CM}=\hat x \bar x+\hat y \bar y$, is given by

$$\begin{align}
\vec r_{CM}&=\frac1M\int_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/6}\int_0^{2\cos(3\theta)} \vec r\,\rho\,r\,dr\,d\theta\\\\
&=\frac3\pi\left(\hat x \int_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/6}\int_0^{2\cos(3\theta)} r^2\cos(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta+\hat y \underbrace{\int_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/6}\int_0^{2\cos(3\theta)} r^2\sin(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta}_{=0\,\text{due to odd symmetry}}\right)\\\\
&=\hat x \frac{16}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/6}\cos^3(3\theta)\cos(\theta)\,d\theta \tag 1
\end{align}$$

The evaluation of the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ is left as an exercise.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got 4p/3. Also, I need the rectangular coordinates for the center of mass.

Comment: This is rectangular coordinates.  What notation do you not understand?

Comment: Okay, thank you. Now, what is ${\hat x}$?

Comment: $\hat x$ is a unit vector along the $x$ axis.

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but it did help me understand. I think I get it now, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I'm just curious ... what is it that you wanted?

Comment: Of course! Sorry for the late response! What I needed was the $({\bar x}, { \bar y })$ coordinates, and between your answer and @Narasimham's answer, I was able to find an answer of my own. Because we're given polar coordinates, and I needed to find the coordinates of the centroid, as $({\bar x}, { \bar y })$. But those coordinates had to be converted to Rectangular. Also, I have up-voted but my reputation is not high enough to show it publicly.

Comment: But I gave you the rectangular coordinates.  What did you not understand?  I'm happy to walk you through this.

Comment: I guess I'm just not familiar with the notation. My Professor taught me to first calculate $M_x = \iint y\rho(x,y)dA$ and then calculate $M_y = \iint x\rho(x,y)dA$ and finally $m = \iint \rho(x,y)dA$. Then, $(\bar x, \bar y) = (\frac{M_y}{m},\frac{M_x}{m})$

Comment: I have edited my original question to show the notes from my professor's lecture. I hope this may clarify some things?

Comment: Tommy, I've given the rectangular coordinates of the center of mass.  $\bar y=0$ and $\bar x=\frac{16}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/y}\cos^3(3\theta)\cos(\theta)\,d\theta$.

Comment: I handed this homework in about a week ago. I know I got $\bar y = 0$, and I'm pretty sure I had a similar answer, obviously I evauated $\bar x$ completely though, I'm see that you left that for me to finish. I've re-accepted your answer.

Comment: Tommy, much appreciated!  And yes, I did leave that trig integral to be evaluated.  It's tedious, but not too tough.

Answer (score 2):

Let me demonstrate how much simpler this problem is in the complex plane. First of all, we note that curve can be expressed as

$$z=2\cos(3\theta)e^{i\theta}$$

The arc length, area, and centroid are given by

$$
s=\int |\dot z| d\theta\\
A=\frac{1}{2}\int \mathfrak{Im}\{z^*\dot z\}d\theta\\
z_c=\frac{1}{3A}\int z\ \mathfrak{Im}\{z^*\dot z\}d\theta
$$

Thus, we need $\dot z$, $z^*$, $\mathfrak{Im}\{z^*\dot z\}$ as follows

$$\dot z=[3\cdot 2\sin(3\theta)+i\cdot2\cos(3\theta)]e^{i\theta}\\
z^*=2\cos(3\theta)e^{-i\theta}\\
\mathfrak{Im}\{z^*\dot z\}=4\cos^2(3\theta)
$$

Then we can readily show that

$$
A=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/6}4\cos^2(3\theta)d\theta=\frac{2}{3}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^2\varphi d\varphi=\frac{\pi}{3}\\
z_c=\frac{8}{3A}\int_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/6}\cos^3(3\theta)e^{i\theta}d\theta=\frac{8}{3A}\int_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/6}\cos^3(3\theta)\cos\theta d\theta=\frac{8}{\pi}\left(\frac{81\sqrt{3}}{320}+0i\right)
$$

Notice the cosine arrangement in the last integral.

Comment: How is this an improvement over a very straightforward real analysis approach?  In fact, it obfuscates the simplicity, I believe.  Please explain your claim "how much simpler this problem is in the complex plane."

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you for your comment. I wrote an essay in response and it was 942 characters over. So this will have to suffice for now.  The complex variable contains more information than the corresponding Cartesian or polar variables. As such, many relations can be simplified. In the present problem, the area and centroid have been expressed as single integrals, instead of doubles. Those integrals are readily solved numerically exactly as is in the complex plane. In fact, I verified my solutions numerically; it took exactly 5 lines of code to get the area and centroid.

Comment: Cye, I don't believe that your assertion is valid.  Look at the solution that I posted and observe its simplicity and efficiency.

Comment: @Dr.MV Mark, we'll just have to agree to disagree. We must likely feel more comfortable with what we know best. Suppose, the curve in question was given parametrically? I would handle it in exactly the same way. In addition, there are many things that can be done in the complex plane that simply cannot be done in Cartesian or polar coordinates. Case in point: show me an equation, say $y(x)$ or $r(\theta)$ for the Fibonacci or Padovan spiral.

Comment: Cye, that's fine.  To clarify the "what we know best" comment, my PhD is in Electromagnetic Field Theory, a discipline involving $3$-D vector fields.  Analysis is often facilitated using integral transforms (e.g., Fourier Transforms) that result in vector fields with complex-valued components.  So, I am perfectly comfortable with complex analysis.  That said, the straightforward calculation of the center of mass is not, I believe, facilitated by complex analysis, despite its elegance as you presented herein.  So, as you wrote, we will agree to disagree.  Hopefully, we are MSE friends.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Mark, You'll be quite surprised to learn that I spent the last 12 years or so before retiring working on low-frequency electromagnetics in stratified media, also for 3-D time dependent fields. At one time I developed an entire Fourier transform and convolution method based on logarithmic temporal and frequency scales to accommodate a problem with highly disparate pulse size and observation time, $\mathcal{O}(10^6)$. (It overwhelmed the FFT because there were too many points.)

Comment: Cye, that is interesting.   My focus was on Integro-Differential descriptions of layered media EM.  I developed EFIE's that exploited symmetry (e.g., longitudinal, rotational) and reduced the EFIE by one dimension (i.e., one of the scalar components, such as $E_z$ or $E_\phi$ was eliminated from the description).  I also published on the Depolarizing Dyad of the EFIE when the excluding region of the PV integral was a "slice."  While at TRW, I researched on time-domain scattering using a "Marching-On-In-Time" approach.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT1

$$   {\bar x} = \frac{\int r ^3\cos \theta d\theta}{\int r^2 d\theta},\, 
  {\bar y} = \frac{\int r ^3\sin \theta d\theta}{\int r^2 d\theta} $$

Plugin $r$ and integrate between given $\theta$ limits. The latter vanishes as for an odd function.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? How will this give me the rectangular coordinates? @Narasimham

Comment: Okay, so my question is, would I plugin $2\cos(3θ)$ for $r$ in these instances? and $-π/6$ and $π/6$ for $θ$? @Narasimham

Comment: This is not correct.  The position vector $\vec r$ is not given by $\hat r r+\hat \theta \theta$.

Comment: @ Tommy Yamakaitis Apologies. I put in in more direct form in edit that I actually wanted to say

Comment: So, you're also saying ${\bar y} = 0$?

Comment: Yes, it is so for a lamina symmetric wrt x-axis.The area of an odd function between same magnitude but opposite sign independent variable limits vanishes.